# Small thumbnail image not appearing in wordpress meta-grid plugin

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Thumbnail image is inside Media-Grid plugin -> Grid Builder -> select any grid from grid list ->small thumbnail image in front of 'select an item' drop down list

Thumbnail image not appear online but work fine locally.
Can you please tell me where to start ? 
here is image
[enter link description here](http://s23.postimg.org/z691lwwuj/pacifico.png)

Answer (score 1):

For cropping thumbnail image, you it would not a proper way to use plugins:

Try with this code, it will helps you for all the rest of thumbnails in your whole site...

Put this code in your `function.php` file

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'custom-post-thumb', 140, 140,true );
}
```

Now use this in your code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

 <?php the_post_thumbnail('custom-post-thumb', array('class' => 'attachment')); // here array('class' => 'attachment') apply if you want to apply class to that anchor tag ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks